# Сменил сервер с windows на *nix. Появилось куча папок. Что с ними делать?

Tags: apache, сервер, linux

Папки:

```
.awstats.cpan.fast.fast-php .php.sshhttplogs
```

и файлы:

```
.bash_logout.bash_profile .bashrs .mounted
```

Если кто знает ресурс по работе сервера **Apache 2.* [l19, Linux], aux1 / fcgi**, напишите. Если не знаете - буду сам искать. Когда работал по виндой, там только одна папка была http. Теперь такое добро высыпало, что я не знаю, как им воспользоваться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файлы с точкой в начале имени обычно относятся к служебным скрытым файлам Linux, например, в файле .bash_profile хранятся настройки профиля пользователя, которые автоматически применяются при запуске оболочки, требующей авторизации. Собственно, обращать внимания на все эти файлы не нужно до тех пор, не потребуется что-то в них менять.

Вся документация по Apache находится на их официальном ресурсе: [Apache HTTP Server Project](http://httpd.apache.org/). На русском можно почитать здесь: [The Apache Modeling Project](http://apachedev.ru/2006/03/12/the-apache-modeling-project-vvedenie/).

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Хоть уже понятно что да как. Буду изучать сервак.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы просматриваете содержимое каталогов через Nautilus, то достаточно во вкладке "Вид" убрать галочку напротив "показывать скрытые папки".